# Get inode number from inside nullfs while reading or writing in FreeBSD 10.2

Tags: c, encryption, freebsd

I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt files as they pass through nullfs for reading and writing but I need the inode number in order to encrypt/decrypt. I was modifying null_open in /usr/src/sys/fs/nullfs/null_vnops.c and trying to find the inode number in the struct vop_open_args *ap
but I couldn't find a way to get the inode number from the struct. Is there any way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to FreeBSD development forum? https://forums.freebsd.org/forums/34/ My feeling is that you will get more help for your issue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do it. I added '

```
MALLOC_DECLARE(M_ATTR);
MALLOC_DEFINE(M_ATTR,"vattr","attribute in null_open");
```

to the top of the file after the includes and

```
    struct vattr *outStuff = malloc(sizeof(struct vattr), M_ATTR, M_ZERO);
    VOP_GETATTR(vp,outStuff,ap->a_cred );
    printf("uid = %d fileid = %ld \n", outStuff->va_uid,outStuff->va_fileid);
    free(outStuff,M_ATTR);
```

in null_open to access the inode from the function parameter.